# Find degree function with max at $(2,44)$ and min at $(4,36)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

> A function has a local maximum at $(2,44)$ and a local minimum value at $(4,36)$. Find a degree function that has these qualities.

I know that the two important points for the $f (x)$ are $2$ and $4$ so $f'(x)=(x-2)(x-4)=x^2-6x+8$ so $f(x)$ should be equal to $f(x)=\dfrac{x^3}3 -3x^2 +8x+d$
but now when I try to find the value of d and it doesn't satisfy the points the answer in the textbook answer key says the answer may vary and that's all they said no example equation so I want to know is this function possible or not and if it is possible I want an example of it with a little bit of explanation of where I was wrong?

I got the answer for anyone who is wondering the answer is that as  $f(x)=a[\dfrac{x^3}3 -3x^2 +8x]+d$ you can find values of a and d and get your equation now!

Comment: Using [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a lot easier than using html.

Comment: This is my first question so I barely knew what to use but I am more confusded about the answer though Thanks a lot for the edit though!BTW can you answer it?

Comment: Read through the link in the above comment so next time you can properly format your answer.

Comment: sure I have test tommorow so I just didn't bother but I'll make sure next time

Comment: but you bothered to write <sup><\sup> which takes up more time?

Comment: ohh I just read something and somewhere and I though this seems something like what I learned in web developing and then just copy paste

Comment: Hint: you can multiply $f'(x)$ by any non-zero constant and still keep its zeros the same. Try instead $f(x)=a\left(\frac{x^3}3 -3x^2 +8x\right)+b\,$.

Comment: makes sense I'll try and tell you if it works or not wait but wouldn't my derivative change then??

Comment: @AgentSmith It will change, but its zeros wil not since $f'(x)=0 \iff a\cdot f'(x)=0$ for $\forall a \ne 0$. Otherwise put, knowing that the quadratic $f'$ has roots $2, 4$ does not mean that $f'(x)=(x-2)(x-4)$ but it means that $f'(x) = a \cdot (x-2)(x-4)$ for some $a\ne 0$.

Comment: truee I tried it and got values of a=8 and d=-28/3 but the problem now is for x=2 y=44 but for x=4 y=33.3333... it's soo close to 36 so should I believe that this is the equation or I messed up somewhere??

Comment: sorry I made a mistake and got values of a=6 and d=4 and they match now!!!! thanks!!! a lot!!!!!!!'

Comment: @AgentSmith FWIW $a=6$ and $b=4$ are right.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing. It was not clear if it is a single variable function or dual-variable function. As the points $(2,44)$ and $(4,36)$ are in the form of $(x,y)$, I consider $y=f(x)$ as the form. Thus, it is a function in one variable.

Now that $(2,44)$ and $(4,36)$ are two points which the function satisfies:

1. $f'(x=2)=0$ because $(2,44)$ is a local maxima. And, $f'(x=4)=0$ because $(4,36)$ is a local minima.
2. $f(x=2)=44$ and $f(x=4)=36$.

From condition `1`,
$$f'(x) = a (x-2)(x-4) \text{ where } a \ne 0$$
$$ \Rightarrow f(x) = a \bigg( \frac{x^3}{3}-3x^2+8x   \bigg)+d$$

From condition `2`, $$f(x=2)=44 \Rightarrow \frac{20}{3}a+b=44$$ and $$f(x=4)=36 \Rightarrow \frac{16}{3}a+b=36$$

Together they yield $$a=6 \text{ and } b=4$$
Thus, the function is $2x^3-18x^2+48x+4$